# _react.default.createContext is not a function when using react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-context

I have a problem when adding components to the entry point, this error immediately pops up here, how to fix it?
I also try add only Main component but anyway i take that error, in main.jsx just class with render method return "hello world"

```
_react.default.createContext is not a function
```

```js
// App.jsx

import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';

import configureStore from './Data/store/configureStore';
import Main from "./Templates/Main/Main";

const store = configureStore();
render(
    <div>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Main/>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </Provider>
    </div>,
    document.getElementById('app-root')
);
```

Webpack config

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
    path.join(__dirname, 'src/app.jsx')
  ],
  resolve: {
    root: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
    ],
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.css']
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/public/'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.tpl.html',
      inject: 'body',
      filename: 'index.html'
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        presets: ['es2015', 'react']
      }
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: 'style!css'
    }]
  }
};
```

and dependencies

```
    "react": "^15.6.2",
    "react-addons-update": "^15.6.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.2",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-select": "^1.0.0-beta13",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "sequelize": "^3.20.0",
    "sqlite3": "^4.0.6"
```

Google advises to upgrade to version 16 of the ract, but I do not think that this is the problem of the old version.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

`react-redux v6.0.0` uses the new context api provided by React and in order for it work, **either you need to downgrade `react-redux` to `v5.x.x`** or **upgrade `react` and `react-dom` to `v16.4` or above**

If you are using yarn, you can run

```
yarn upgrade react react-dom
```

else with npm you can run

```
npm update react react-dom
```

You could also change the versions manually in package.json and run `yarn install` or `npm install`

Comment: yup, thatnk, change to old version react-redux help!

Comment: If its possible to upgrade react, i will advise you to do that, since there are a number of good features available in the newer versions

Comment: yup, but maybe later, for test task 15 version be enough :)

Comment: Cool, glad to have helped though

Comment: Hi @ShubhamKhatri I am getting this error when I am using react-i18n library. What can be the issue?

Comment: @Ashh, can you share more details on its version. and whether its react-18next or react-i18n

Comment: FFS why do they have to change things all the time??!??? its impossible to work with

Comment: In my case, it worked with react & react-dom version 16.2 too

Comment: This fixes error related to using "react-transition-group v4.4.1" with "react v16.0.0" and "react-dom v16.0.0" as well. Running npm update fixed the issue for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 38):

I got the same issue but updating react and react-dom didn't help.
I was using NextJS 13 with react-hook-form and the problem was that I forgot to put "use client" on the top of the page. This error occurred because you can't use hooks in server components.

ex:

```
"use client"; // top to the file
```

Extra info: [Next.js Error: Hooks are not Allowed in Server Components](https://www.slingacademy.com/article/next-js-error-hooks-are-not-allowed-in-server-components/)

Comment: You saved my day! 

Answer (score 7):

Got the issue fixed by updating the react and react-dom

```
npm update react react-dom
```

And ofcourse closing the server and restarting by npm start again.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you git pull or use someone's else code, try updating your package to the latest version using:

`npm update`

**always check the React/React-dom versions, especially when you have imported project while following any online course !!**

Also, if you don't want to update all packages by npm update just do :

`npm i react@latest react-dom@latest`

*I Hope this helps !!*

Answer (score 1):

Try installing with this version:  `yarn add react-redux@5.0.5`

Answer (score 0):

i had this error

```
_react.default.createContext is not a function
```

then I updated the react and react-dom to the latest version
by using

```
npm update react react-dom
```

and this solved my problem .

Answer (score 0):

for me it was a version conflict , i updated npm first then i ran npm install, try fist :

```
npm i npm@latest -g
```

then

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading react-dom package worked for me - try either of these (depending on your package manager)

- npm update react react-dom

---

### OR

- yarn upgrade react react-dom