# _react.default.createContext is not a function when using @material-ui/core

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Im getting the following error when trying to import components from @material-ui/core:

```
FormControlContext.js?f516:15 Uncaught TypeError: _react.default.createContext is not a function
    at eval (FormControlContext.js?f516:15)
    at Object../node_modules/@material-ui/core/FormControl/FormControlContext.js (main-e0a237440313c16428eb.js:6062)
    at __webpack_require__ (main-e0a237440313c16428eb.js:725)
    at fn (main-e0a237440313c16428eb.js:102)
    at eval (InputBase.js?f12e:38)
    at Object../node_modules/@material-ui/core/InputBase/InputBase.js (main-e0a237440313c16428eb.js:6230)
    at __webpack_require__ (main-e0a237440313c16428eb.js:725)
    at fn (main-e0a237440313c16428eb.js:102)
    at eval (index.js?26dc:15)
    at Object../node_modules/@material-ui/core/InputBase/index.js
```

**Ive already tried (suggested: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54521723/react-default-createcontext-is-not-a-function-when-using-react-redux)):**

- npm update react react-dom

Any ideas how this can be resolved?

Comment: Use -  npm install @material-ui/core may be work.

Comment: I am also getting the same error, were you able to resolve it? I can't upgrade to latest version as the current code base is on v15.