# react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.createContext is not a function error persist despite version align

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I get this error:

> react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.createContext is not a function

I see all the others questions related to this topic but with no success, my versions is this :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@south-paw/react-vector-maps": "^3.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap-calendar": "0.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-regex": "^1.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
```

I also create a new react empty project but the result is the same and i really don't know how to solve the problem at this time

-----EDIT-----

I uninstalled and installed again nodejs and npm and i create a new project using yarn instead, now the problem is solved but anyway i still don't understand the meaning of this error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\_react.default.createContext is not a function when using react-redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54521723/react-default-createcontext-is-not-a-function-when-using-react-redux)

Comment: unfortunately no, i've tried to downgrade the version of react-redux but with no results unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by uninstilling react and nodejs, probably i've done some mistake with versions